# Validate pipe separated line against specified format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am reading lines from a text file. each line is pipe separated. I want to validate the line i.e each item is according to a specified format after splitting by delimiter. eg:- Here is my line

```
D|111111|87654321|Bar|BCreace|GBP|24/08/2010
```

Check if the above line follows the following format for eg:

```
Field Ref Field Length  
S0          1
S1          6
S2          34
...
S6          10
```

Currently i am using if condition as below:

```
    var sortCode = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(items[1], out sortCode) || items[1].Length > 6)
        errorMessage.Add("Sort Code", "Invalid sort code");
```

But can anyone help me if this can be done in a proper way?

Thanks

Comment: This code looks fine to me.  You could probably reduce the code by creating an int array for the length requirements, and an array for the possible error messages.  Then just loop through.  Otherwise, it looks good.

Comment: If you have working code and just want it reviewed then [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better site to post on.

Comment: I'd recommend posting the entire method if you're interested in a peer review. One-liners aren't the greatest questions on [codereview.se].

Comment: Thank you. i have posted my code in code review.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing `sortCode` to `0` is redundant, because an `out` parameter is guaranteed by the compiler to be initialized by the `TryParse` function... and the default value for an `int` value type is 0 anyway.

So instead of this:

```
var sortCode = 0;
```

You could have this:

```
int sortCode;
```

---

> ```
> if (!int.TryParse(items[1], out sortCode) || items[1].Length > 6)
> ```

`6` is a magic number here, it would be better to make it a constant with a meaningful name. Also, there *might* be a bit too much logic crammed into that one line. How about this?

```
var parsed = int.TryParse(items[1], out sortCode);
if (!parsed || items[1].Length > SORTCODE_LENGTH)
{
    errorMessage.Add("Sort Code", "Invalid sort code");
}
```

Depending on context, throwing an exception might be a better idea here - if your method is doing more than what you've shown, it's probably doing too many things and could benefit from another abstraction level.

Notice the explicit scope under the `if` - for an example of what can happen with implicit scopes, try searching for "Apple SSL goto fail" ;-)

---

If this is the kind of answer you're looking for, you need to try [Code Review](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

There is no one proper way of doing this but I have a suggestion for you that uses a custom attribute.

I named it `ColumnInfoAttribute`:

```
class ColumnInfoAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
}
```

It allows you to specify the index and max length of a field so you can apply it all properties that should receive a value:

```
class LineItem
{
    [ColumnInfo(Index = 0, MaxLength = 1)]
    public string S0 { get; set; }

    [ColumnInfo(Index = 1, MaxLength = 6)]
    public string S1 { get; set; }

    [ColumnInfo(Index = 2, MaxLength = 34)]
    public string S2 { get; set; }

    [ColumnInfo(Index = 3, MaxLength = 34)]
    public string S3 { get; set; }

    [ColumnInfo(Index = 4, MaxLength = 34)]
    public string S4 { get; set; }

    [ColumnInfo(Index = 5, MaxLength = 34)]
    public string S5 { get; set; }

    [ColumnInfo(Index = 6, MaxLength = 34)]
    public DateTime S6 { get; set; }

    public static LineItem Parse(string line)
    {
        var propertyDictionary =
            typeof(LineItem)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            // create an anonymous object to hold the property and the ColumnInfo
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Property = p,
                ColumnInfo = p.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnInfoAttribute>()
            })
            // get only those where the ColumnInfo is not null (in case there are other properties)
            .Where(ci => ci.ColumnInfo != null)
            // create a dictionary with the Index as a key
            .ToDictionary(ci => ci.ColumnInfo.Index);

        var result = new LineItem();

        var values = line.Split('|');
        for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            // validate the length of the value
            var isValidLength = values[i].Length > propertyDictionary[i].ColumnInfo.MaxLength;
            if (!isValidLength)
            {
                // todo: throw some appropriate exception or do other error handling
            }

            // set the corresponding property
            var converterdValue = Convert.ChangeType(
                values[i], 
                propertyDictionary[i].Property.PropertyType);
            propertyDictionary[i].Property.SetValue(result, converterdValue);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The same class has also a `Parse` method that via reflection gets all properties with the `ColumnInfo` attribute and creates a dictionary. The key of the dictionary is the `Index`.

Now you can for-loop over all values and use the `i` to get a `ColumnInfo`. You then check if the length of the field is valid and if so you use the `property.SetValue` to assign a value to the property.

Usage:

```
var line = "D|111111|87654321|Bar|BCreace|GBP|24/08/2010";
var lineItem = LineItem.Parse(line);
```

It's easily extensible and very generic. If you have more such cases you can put this code in a base class and add the attributes to the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little less performant but I find it easier to read and maintain.
You can parse the line to a strongly typed object then validate the object.
In the example below I am using [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation).

```
public class LineItem
{
    public static LineItem Parse(string line)
    {
        var split = line.Split('|');
        return new LineItem(split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4], split[5], split[6]);
    }

    public LineItem(string s0, string s1, string s2, string s3, string s4, string s5, string s6)
    {
        //any param value checks

        S0 = s0;
        S1 = s1;
        S2 = s2;
        S3 = s3;
        S4 = s4;
        S5 = s5;
        S6 = s6;
    }

    public string S0 { get; set; }
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public string S3 { get; set; }
    public string S4 { get; set; }
    public string S5 { get; set; }
    public string S6 { get; set; }
}

public class LineItemValidator : AbstractValidator<LineItem>
{
    public LineItemValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(line => line.S0).Length(1);
        RuleFor(line => line.S2).Length(6);
        //etc
    }
}
```

Then usage would be something like this:

```
public class FileValidatorTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Spike()
    {
        var line = "D|111111|87654321|Bar|BCreace|GBP|24/08/2010";
        var lineItem = LineItem.Parse(line);
        var result = new LineItemValidator().Validate(lineItem);
        Assert.True(result.IsValid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about a regex?

```
[^|]\|[^|]{6}\|[^|]{8}\|[^|]{3}\|[^|]{7}\|[^|]{3}\|[^|]{10}
```

Try it out here https://regex101.com/r/rI6zN6/1